# UIColor.blackColor() somewhat less than black on Tab Bar

Tags: xcode, swift, uitabbar, uicolor

I am setting my Tab Bar to be black. Only it makes it dark gray, not black. See attached image. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Set the `translucent` property to `false`.

Comment: Nice one Guillaume. Put that as the answer and I'll tick it, if you want?

Comment: glad it was that simple. I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab bar is rendered gray because of translucency. [This is the default](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/translucent):

> If the tab bar does not have a custom background image, the default value is `YES`.

Set its [`translucent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/translucent) property to `false` to fix this and get a 100% black tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = false
```

> try above line